# DB2 Alter Table and add Hash

Tags: hash, db2, partition, alter

Is it possible to alter an existing table in DB2 to add a hash partition? Something like...

```
ALTER TABLE EXAMPLE.TEST_TABLE
PARITION BY HASH(UNIQUE_ID)
```

Thanks!

Comment: What is your Db2-server platform ( Z/os,  i-series,  Linux/unix/windows ) ?  And your Db2-version?

Comment: zlinux, version 11

Comment: is the zLinux hosting the database natively, or has it just a Db2-client to Db2-for-z/os on a different subsystem?

Comment: Do you run your zLinux Db2 in DPF (partitioned database environment)? If no, then it's useless to use the `distribute` clause.

Comment: Yes it's running in a partitioned environment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you run a Db2-LUW local server on zLinux, the following syntax may be available:

`ALTER TABLE .. ADD DISTRIBUTE BY HASH (...)`

This syntax is not available if the zLinux is not running a Db2-LUW server but is instead only a client of Db2-for-z/OS.

For this syntax to be meaningful, there are various pre-requisites. Refer to the documentation for details of partitioned instances, database partition groups , distribution key rules and default behaviours etc.

The intention of distributed tables (spread over multiple physical and/or logical partitions of a partitioned database in a partitioned Db2-instance) is to exploit hardware capabilities. So if your Db2-instance and database and tablespaces are not appropriately configured, this syntax has limited value.

Depending on your true motivations, `partition by range` may offer functionality that is useful.  Note that `partition by range` can be combined with `distribute by hash` if the configuration is appropriate.

Comment: Don't think I can do it on my setup then, thank you for the answer!